# How to delete vault secret using null resource in terraform

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

@all

I have written a code to create a vault secret using null_resource but I am getting one error when I run terraform validate

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = create
    command = "curl -k -H 'X-Vault-Token: ${var.VAULT_TOKEN}' -X POST --data @$PWD/config/kubeconfig.json ${var.VAULT_ADDR}/v1/secret/aws/tsys${module.init.current_account_name_lower}/${local.region}/eks_linux/${local.cluster_name}/kubeconfig"
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.copy_kube_config
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "delete_vault_config" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    command = "curl -k -H 'X-Vault-Token: ${var.VAULT_TOKEN}' -X DELETE ${var.VAULT_ADDR}/v1/secret/aws/vkhello${module.init.current_account_name_lower}/${local.region}/eks_linux/${local.cluster_name}/kubeconfig"
  }
}


Error: Invalid reference from destroy provisioner
│ 
│   on main.tf line 42, in resource "null_resource" "delete_vault_config":
│   42:     command = "curl -k -H 'X-Vault-Token: ${var.VAULT_TOKEN}' -X DELETE ${var.VAULT_ADDR}/v1/secret/aws/vkhello${module.init.current_account_name_lower}/${local.region}/eks_linux/${local.cluster_name}/kubeconfig"
│ 
│ Destroy-time provisioners and their connection configurations may only reference attributes of the related resource, via 'self', 'count.index', or 'each.key'.
│ 
│ References to other resources during the destroy phase can cause dependency cycles and interact poorly with create_before_destroy.
```

Is there a way to delete the vault secret using null resource only when I run terraform destroy?

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't like the reference to a module and possibly the locals. Referencing a module that may not exist during destroy could create issues.

Comment: Why not use the Vault provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs